# CSS: can't understand how to work with the z-index

Tags: jquery, html, css, z-index

First of all I am a programmer (Python, C, Java, Delphi, whatever) and not a web developer/designer. I am trying hard to be (when asked) so please bear with me. :-)

I have a map (background image of div). On the map I have placed some cities (div with image). Underneath the cities there are cars (div with image, too). Each car can travel to any city (drag-drop, I am working on this now). Cities and cars, when clicked-once, show pop up dialogs with extra information.

Up to here, no news. What a normal programmer would want is to have the map on the first level (i.e. z-index 0) cities on the next (i.e. z-index 10) cars on the next (z-index 20 because when dragged and dropped cars should appear above the cities and not bellow) and finally above all the popups (z-index 999).

However this is not the case. Cars when dragged "fly" above some cities and "pass" below some other (depending if they were placed before or after the city while rendering the page, I suppose).

I was trying hard to place a div (to draw lines) in between the map div and the cities (ie z-index 5) but to no avail.

Popups also have problems.

I also tried this piece of code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   map_zindex = $("#map").css("z-index");
   $(".city").css("z-index", map_zindex+10);
   $(".car").css("z-index", map_zindex+100);
   $(".popup").css("z-index", map_zindex+200);
});
```

Still nothing changes (not even a small progress). Nothing. Worst of all, when checking with [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug) I was getting a `z-index: auto;` to all of those elements.

I know I must be doing something completely wrong, but what is it? I hope my dislike for CSS is not causing all this mess.

Comment: make sure they all are positioned either relatively or absolutly

Comment: i assume all the divs in question have `position: absolute` or `position:relative`. HAve you tried using a stylsheet to jsut set all the divs of a certain type to a z-index like `.city {z-index: 10;} .car {z-index: 20;} .popup {z-index: 30;}`?

Comment: Your question title is just begging for a downvote.

Comment: @prodigitalson: yes. That was my first move.

Comment: @Breezer. yes they are. @hobbs. Why? Didn't mean to offend anyone. Shall I change it? I can change it.

Comment: @xpanta: I can't speak for hobbs, but I can have a guess at it. 1: You're not missing a single opportunity to point out that you don't want to be doing web, what 'a normal programmer' would want and how frustrated you are for things not working the way you expect. This was most blatantly the case in the title, that has now been fixed. We just want to know what the problem is, not how it makes you feel. You write things like "Worst of all, when checking with firebug I was getting `z-index: auto`". That's not worst of all. That's pretty much the *only* useful clue to what is wrong in there.

Comment: You can rule out a lot by observing that the z-index actually hasn't been set. 2. There's just a little fragment of code in here, and it's under "I also tried...". What was your initial approach? Z-index works, so there's something you haven't done right. You can tell from the follow-up-question to actual-answer ratio that you haven't provided us with enough info. 3. At Stack Overflow, when you receive an answer that you're happy with, you tick the box under that question to mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Positioned elements (absolutely or relatively) will always have a higher z-index than other elements, so unless you position all your elements (you don't need to set their `top` and `left` values, just their `position` value), this will be a possible cause of some problems.

However, since you're saying the elements show up as `z-index: auto` in firebug, I suspect something else is wrong. Is the z-index applied only with jQuery? In that case, it looks like the code is being executed before the elements are available on the page. Otherwise, please give us a js fiddle recreating this error.

Also note that with jQuery draggables, you can alter their z-index as they are dragged:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#visual-feedback

Comment: thanks, is this the same for elements inside positioned elements? For instance if my div holding an image is relatively positioned, should the image inside the div (or other inner-divs) also be positioned?

Comment: also, with jQuery, be careful about the naming of CSS properties containing a dash "-" if used as .css( propertyName, value ) or .css( map ) : .css("z-index", 100) vs .css( {zIndex : 100 }) ... I don't think it is related but who knows ? :)

Comment: @tsimbalar: it's valid to quote the property name in the latter example as well, `.css({ 'z-index': 100 })`. I don't think that's what's happening here, as the code is accurate in the example, but you're right, it's something one has to look out for.

Comment: I just noticed that .cars and .popups are all children of the city (which they appear underneath) <div> element. Is this connected somehow with my initial question?

Answer (score 2):

Solved:

The problem was that in the {% for city in cities %} loop which inserted all the cities on the map, I created all other elements (cars and popups) as children of the city . This was confusing because I didn't know that children inherit the z-index from their parents (this is the 'Cascading' in CSS anyway). Now I made all elements children of the #map element and everything is fine.

Thank you all for your information. It helped more than you can imagine.

Answer (score 0):

The z-index of an element only takes affect when you change the default position of the item. I would recommend something like the following.

```
.popup {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Also keep in mind that the order of DOM elements can also affect the position of an item.

Comment: my popups are absolute positioned and have a z-index of 100. Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

The initial value of z-index is 'auto'.  So if you don't have defined a numeric z-index for #map somewhere, you try to assign a value of 'auto10', what's illegal, the z-index will not change.

So you need to assign a numeric value to the z-index of #map  to get it working.
To get the expected result, you also have to make a Number of the returned numeric value:

```
map_zindex = Number($("#map").css("z-index"));
```

Otherwise(assuming a z-index of 10) you will assign to .city a value of 1010(because css("z-index") returns a string '10', not a Number 10, what results into a string-concatenation instead of an addition)

Comment: Thanks, I've never thought of that. Initial value of #map is 10 (given in the css file)